# Lightweight solution to define lots of same icons in svg

Tags: html, svg

What is the most lightweight solution to display many copies (~500) of the same icon at different positions in an svg?

I could use **`use`**:

```html
<svg>
    <defs> <image id="ic" href="icon.svg" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/> </defs>
    ...
    <use x="130" y="140" href="#ic"/>
    <use x="137" y="123" href="#ic"/>
    ...
</svg>
```

But there's the href (repeated information) that I have to give every time.

If content modification were supported in svg, I could do:

```html
<style>
    .icon { font-family: iconfont; }
    .icon:before { content: "\e9c1"; } <!-- so I don't have to put &#xe9c1; every time -->
</style>
<svg>
    <g class="icon">
        ...
        <text x="130" y="140"></text>
        <text x="137" y="123"></text>
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

But sadly, svg elements are replaced elements.

Can we avoid repeated information?

Comment: oops I'll update the question

Comment: The most lightweight thing is likely to be to use a canvas and draw everything on that. Or if the icons are spaced regularly, use a pattern.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's a nice way too.